# Rewrite issue with Nginx

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt

I would like any request done to :

<my_url>/.well-known/acme-challenge/<any_string_here>

to be rewrited to <my_url>/.well-known/acme-challenge/ and send a 200 response (not a 301 redirection).

Here is my nginx configuration:

```
location ~ /\.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
       allow all;
      default_type "text/plain";
      root /var/www/certbot;
      try_files $uri =200;
      break;
    }

    location ~ /\.well-known/acme-challenge/(.*)$ {
        rewrite /\.well-known/acme-challenge/(.*)$ /\.well-known/acme-challenge/ break;
    }
```

request to /.well-known/acme-challenge/ work perfectly and returns "OK", but requests to path such as /.well-known/acme-challenge/random_string returns a 404 instead of a 200 with a "OK".

Any idea what is wrong with my second location?

Thanks a lot